# HTML Tables in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

Using the following code:

```
<table border="1" >
<?
    $item_count=0;  
    $select_SQL="select * from iplay_test";
    $result=mysql_query($select_SQL,$con);
    while($eachRow= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        if($item_count%3==0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td> 0 </td></tr>";           
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td> 1</td>";
        }

    $item_count++;
    }

    ?>      
</table>
```

I am getting the output ,

```
0
1    1
0
1    1
0
1    1
0
1    1
0
1    1
```

But I should be getting something like

```
0 1 1 
0 1 1
0 1 1
```

What am I missing here?

I am basically doing this to get 3 items displayed per row. The data to be displayed will be from a database. Is there any better solution for this problem?.

Comment: As for something better... https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

Comment: What does the HTML look like? You should spot such a problem at once as you inspect the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code as below, solved my problem. Thanks to [Jasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376505/jasha)

```
<table border="1" >

    <tr>
    <?
    $item_count=0;

    $select_SQL="select * from iplay_test";
    $result=mysql_query($select_SQL,$con);
    while($eachRow= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {


    if($item_count%3==0)
    {
        if($item_count==0)
        {
        echo "<td> 0</td>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "</tr><tr><td> 0 </td>";
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td> 1</td>";

    }

        $item_count++;
    }

?>  

</tr>   
    </table>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to close the last row (there's no `</tr>` after the `?>`)

Answer (score 3):

You're opening and closing the row on every third cell. The opening tr tag should be before the first cell, while the closing tag should be after the third cell.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting a new row for every record:

```
        echo "<tr><td> 0 </td></tr>";
              ^^^^--- starts a new row
```

move the `<tr>` and `</tr>` out of this echo, and issue them only after every 3rd record, so you get something more like

```
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the `<tr>`

```
while($eachRow= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    echo '<tr>';
    if($item_count%3==0)
    {
        echo "<td>0</td>";           
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td>1</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    $item_count++;
}
```